# Why is my Spring @Autowired not work in this Web Service

Tags: java, spring, nullpointerexception, null, autowired

I Create one Web Service Using JAX-WS but I cant inject a Bean using @Autowired

I tried many things with no success.

Anyone have some ideas to help me on this problem?

Thanks so much.

IndicadoresBSTSWebServiceImpl:

```
package com.santander.portalcio.ws;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.jws.WebService;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.SpringBeanAutowiringSupport;

import com.santander.portalcio.backend.entities.IncidentType;
import                 
com.santander.portalcio.backend.services.bsts.indicators.BSIndicatorVO;
import com.santander. 
portalcio.backend.services.bsts.indicators.BSTSIndicatorsFilterVO;
import 
com.santander.portalcio.backend.services.bsts.indicators.EntityIndicatorVO;
import 

com.santander.
portalcio.backend.services.bsts.indicators.FunctionalityIndicatorVO;
import com.santander.
portalcio.backend.services.bsts.indicators.TSIndicatorVO;
import com.santander.
portalcio.ui.managedbean.home.HomeIndicadoresReportService;

@Service
@WebService(endpointInterface =         
"com.santander.
portalcio.ws.IndicadoresBSTSWebServiceInterface")
public class IndicadoresBSTSWebServiceImpl extends                     
SpringBeanAutowiringSupport 
implements IndicadoresBSTSWebServiceInterface {


@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
}

@Autowired
private HomeIndicadoresReportService homeIndicadoresReportService;

private List<EntityIndicatorVO> resultMesAtual;

private BSTSIndicatorsFilterVO filter = new BSTSIndicatorsFilterVO();

private EntityIndicatorVO selectedEntity = new EntityIndicatorVO();
private BSIndicatorVO selectedBS = new BSIndicatorVO();
private TSIndicatorVO selectedTS = new TSIndicatorVO();
private FunctionalityIndicatorVO selectedFunctionality = new     
FunctionalityIndicatorVO();


@Override
public ListaWS teste() {
    filter.setStart(new Date("01/01/2016"));
    filter.setEnd(new Date("01/31/2016"));
    IncidentType[] tipo = { IncidentType.BATCH, IncidentType.ONLINE };
    filter.setTypeList(tipo);
    resultMesAtual = new ArrayList<EntityIndicatorVO>();

    homeIndicadoresReportService.buildValuesToGraph(resultMesAtual, 
    selectedEntity, selectedBS, selectedTS,
            selectedFunctionality, filter, false);


    return new ListaWS(resultMesAtual);
    }

}
```

IndicadoresBSTSWebServiceInterface :

```
package com.santander.portalcio.ws;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Style;

@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC, parameterStyle = ParameterStyle.WRAPPED)
public interface IndicadoresBSTSWebServiceInterface {

@WebMethod
ListaWS teste();

}
```

web.XML :

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>indicadoresBSTS</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>indicadoresBSTS</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/indicadoresBSTS</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

HomeIndicadoresReportService :

```
package com.santander.portalcio.ui.managedbean.home;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import     com.santander.
portalcio.backend.services.bsts.indicators.BSIndicatorVO;
import com.santander.
portalcio.backend.services.bsts.indicators.BSTSIndicatorsFilterVO;
import com.santander.
portalcio.backend.services.bsts.indicators.EntityIndicatorVO;
import com.santander.
portalcio.backend.services.bsts.indicators.FunctionalityIndicatorVO;
import com.santander.
portalcio.backend.services.bsts.indicators.TSIndicatorVO;

public interface HomeIndicadoresReportService extends Serializable {

public void selectAndBuildEntityBsTsFunc
(List<EntityIndicatorVO> resultAux,     BSTSIndicatorsFilterVO filter);

public void selectcompFuncInc
(List<EntityIndicatorVO> resultAux, EntityIndicatorVO selectedEntity,
        BSIndicatorVO selectedBS, 
TSIndicatorVO selectedTS, FunctionalityIndicatorVO selectedFunctionality,
        BSTSIndicatorsFilterVO filter, boolean isIndicatorsBSTS);

public void selectTotaoInc
(List<EntityIndicatorVO> resultAux, EntityIndicatorVO selectedEntity,
        BSIndicatorVO selectedBS, 
TSIndicatorVO selectedTS,         
FunctionalityIndicatorVO     selectedFunctionality, 
BSTSIndicatorsFilterVO filter);

public void buildValuesToGraph
(List<EntityIndicatorVO> resultMes,     EntityIndicatorVO selectedEntity,
        BSIndicatorVO selectedBS, 
TSIndicatorVO selectedTS, FunctionalityIndicatorVO selectedFunctionality,
        BSTSIndicatorsFilterVO filter, boolean isIndicatorsBSTS);

}
```

HomeIndicadoresReportServiceBean:

```
package com.santander.portalcio.ui.managedbean.home;
@Repository
@Transactional(propagation = 
Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor =     Exception.class)
public class HomeIndicadoresReportServiceBean 
implements HomeIndicadoresReportService {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 6513587371275348695L;

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

@Autowired
private UnavailabilityValidationHelper unavailabilityHelper;

@Autowired
private FunctionalityAvailableService functionalityAvailableService;

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###");
DecimalFormat dfHour = new DecimalFormat("00");

@Override
public void buildValuesToGraph(List<EntityIndicatorVO> 
resultMes, EntityIndicatorVO selectedEntity,
        BSIndicatorVO selectedBS, TSIndicatorVO 
selectedTS, FunctionalityIndicatorVO selectedFunctionality,
        BSTSIndicatorsFilterVO filter, boolean isIndicatorsBSTS) {

    selectAndBuildEntityBsTsFunc(resultMes, filter);

    selectcompFuncInc(resultMes, selectedEntity, 
selectedBS, selectedTS, selectedFunctionality, filter,
            isIndicatorsBSTS);
```

Answer (score 0):

While you are attempting to autowire HomeIndicadoresReportService, it does not appear that you have configured that as a Spring bean. You can either annotate that HomeIndicadoresReportService class with @Service, create an XML config entry in your application context file, or create a @Bean configuration method for this in your Java configuration class (depending on how you have configured your Spring context).

Comment: I'm not sure if my project have one Spring Configuration, do you have one example for this solution?

Comment: I add more 2 classes